# how to connect your own data's date in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny-reactivity

I am new to R shiny

I am make date Input and trying to connect with my own data.

I have data called performance and here is example of data

Date          A      B
2020-08-01   10     100
2020-09-01   15     250
2020-10-01   16     300
2020-11-01   20     350

I want the date of my data set can be reactive but I am not quite get how can I do that.

Here is code that I got so far.
When I run this code the date range select bar appear but it doesn't work if I press certain date.

```
  ui <- fluidPage(

  title = "Performance",

   dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Date range:",
             start = "2020-08-01",
             end   = "2020-11-01"),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(

      conditionalPanel(

        'input.dataset === "performance"',

        checkboxGroupInput("show_vars", "Columns in diamonds to show:",

                           names(performance), selected = names(performance))

      ),

    mainPanel(

      tabsetPanel(

        id = 'dataset',

        tabPanel("diamonds", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1"))

        
      )

    )

  )

)

 

server <- function(input, output) {

  filteredData <- reactive({
  req(input$dateRange)
  peformance[peformance$date>= input$dateRange[1] & peformance$date <= input$dateRange[2],]


})



  performance2 = performance[sample(nrow(performance), 1000), ]

  output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable(performance2[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE])

  })
  

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This hopefully is a working example to help you.

To get this working, a number of corrections were needed.

First, the `ui` id for `dateRangeInput` was `daterange1` - I made this `daterange` and made sure was consistent in `server`. Note, this is case-sensitive, so `dateRange` with a capital "R" won't work with `daterange`.

I left out the conditional panel. This can be included depending on what you intend the behavior to have. For now, it was permanently hiding your `checkBoxGroupInput`.

In `server`, your `reactive` expression should be called when the dates change. In this case, it will subset based on your dates and sampled (I tried to leave in your code as much as possible).

To incorporate the resulting data in your `datatable`, you can refer to the `reactive` expression as `filteredData()`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Performance",
  dateRangeInput("daterange", "Date range:",
                 start = "2020-08-01",
                 end   = "2020-11-01"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        checkboxGroupInput("show_vars", "Columns in diamonds to show:",
                           names(performance), selected = names(performance)
                           )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = 'dataset',
        tabPanel("diamonds", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1"))
      )
    )
  )
)
  
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  filteredData <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange)
    df <- performance[performance$Date >= input$daterange[1] &
                      performance$Date <= input$daterange[2], ]
    df[sample(nrow(df), 1000, replace = T), ]
  })
  
  output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(filteredData()[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE])
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment and kind explanation! It works now

Comment: Can I ask you one more question, if I want to add reactive with 'numericInput' how can I do that? Do I need to create another reactive function?

Comment: You can reference a `numericInput` in the same `reactive` expression.

Comment: @ Ben, filteredData <- reactive({
                   req(input$daterange)
             df <- performance[performance$Date >= input$daterange[1] &
                                          performance$Date <= input$daterange[2] & performance$A >=input$num[1] & performance$A <=input$num[2],]
    df[sample(nrow(df), 1000, replace = T), ]
  }) Is it the right way to reference a numeric input?

Comment: @H.Cho I answered your other question - hope this is helpful.